# Conditions about Kahler metric

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose there is a Kahler metric
$$ h=h_{i\bar{j}}dz^i \bar{dz^j}$$

then get

$$ \frac{\partial h_{i\bar{j}} }{\partial z^k}=\frac{\partial h_{k\bar{j}} }{\partial z^i}$$

then claimed locally,there is a function $\Phi$,such that

$$ \frac{\partial ^{2} \Phi}{\partial z^i\partial \bar{z^j} }=h_{i\bar{j}}$$

I tired hours but failed follow the Frobenius Thm.

I will appreciate if you give any help.

Thank you for the help of AHusain!

Let $$\phi=h_{i\bar{j}}dz^i \wedge \bar{dz^j}$$

then by $$d\phi=0$$
locally

(#)$$\phi=dw $$

$w$ is a 1-form,$w=u+v$,$u$is a (1,0)form,$v$ is a (0,1)form.

Sine (#),
$$ \partial u= 
\bar{\partial} v=0$$

locally $$u=\partial g$$

$$v=\bar{\partial}f$$

$f,g$ is a function,then get the dersired $\Phi = f-g $

Comment: Do you want a proof of Poincare Lemma?

Comment: Any hints ! Thanks